# SQL - how can I use AND operator that will work after using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a "PRODUCTS" table :

```
id | name
---------
1  | nike
2  | adidas
```

and "FILTERS" table :

```
id | name
---------
1  | red
2  | blue
```

and "PRODUCTS_FILTERS" table :

```
product_id | filter_id
-----------------------
     1     |     1
     1     |     2
     2     |     2
```

I need a SQL query that will return only the products that have `filter1` AND `filter2` ('nike' product in my example).

When I run the following SQL query :

```
select products.* from products 
join product_filters on products.id = product_filters.productId 
join filters on product_filters.filterId = filters.id
where filters.id = 1 AND filters.id = 2
```

Even though the "nike" product has the `filter1` (red) and `filter2` (blue) in the `PRODUCTS_FILTERS` I don't get any results because the `join` makes 2 different rows for the `nike` product.

How can I fix my query?

Comment: seems strange filters.id =1 AND filters.id =2    ... you can check only a value for  id  .. ( the logic say  .. or is equle to1 or is equal to 2  but not to both)

Comment: Nothing is returned because there is no entry which is both id=1 and id=2.
You should add `COUNT(*) AS cnt` field to SELECT, and then group results by product_id, so you can use OR: `(filters.id=1 OR filters.id=2) AND cnt=2` in  WHERE clause

Comment: What @DevilaN said, but `cnt=2` will need to be in a `HAVING` clause, and you may want to change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT filters.id)` if you're paranoid about potentially having multiple references to the same `filters.id`.

Comment: Also, you technically don't need to join to the `filters` table; you can use `product_filters.filterId`.

Comment: @DevilaN Can you please write the query with your "count" addition ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT products.*
      FROM products
INNER JOIN products_filters 
        ON product_filters.productId = products.id
INNER JOIN filters 
        ON filters.id = product_filters.filterId
       AND filters.id in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(DISTINCT pf.filter_id) AS cnt
FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_filters pf
ON (pf.product_id=p.id)
WHERE pf.filter_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING cnt=2;
```

Resulting in:

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | cnt |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | nike |   2 |
+----+------+-----+
```

PS. Big thanks to @Uueerdo for help with correcting my previous query.

Comment: is there any way to change this query so it will support this : 
'WHERE (pf.filter_id = 1 or pf.filter_id = 2) AND (pf.filterId = 3).
in this case I want that count (2) will return products with 1 and 3 /// 2 and 3 and not product with 1 and 2.

Comment: @mashiah: This is a matter of simple logic. What you are describing is not 1 OR 1 but either 1 OR 2. You should construct condition as ((=1 AND !=2) OR (=2 AND !=1)) AND =3
Another (same logic) example will be (=1 AND =3) OR (=2 AND =3)